# Merging of Two Array in React Native/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have an Array lets say

```
arr1 =  [ 
{date: "June 27", data: ["dummyone","dummy2",...]},
{date: "June 24", data: ["dummyone","dummy2",...]},
{date: "June 18", data: ["dummyone","dummy2",...]},
{date: "June 14", data: ["dummyone","dummy2",...]}
]

arr2 = [ 
{date: "June 14", data: ["dummy3","dummy4",...]},
{date: "June 12", data: ["dummy3","dummy4",...]},
{date: "June 10", data: ["dummy3","dummy4",...]},
{date: "June 09", data: ["dummy3","dummy4",...]}
]
```

So my final array should be

```
[ 
{date: "June 27", data: ["dummyone","dummy2",...]},
{date: "June 24", data: ["dummyone","dummy2",...]},
{date: "June 18", data: ["dummyone","dummy2",...]},
{date: "June 14", data: ["dummyone","dummy2","dummy3","dummy4",...]},
{date: "June 12", data: ["dummy3","dummy4",...]},
{date: "June 10", data: ["dummy3","dummy4",...]},
{date: "June 09", data: ["dummy3","dummy4",...]}
]
```

I have tried merging the array for "June 14" date, also tried using spread operator like (lastDateLoaded has "June 14" as value)

```
arr2.forEach(activitiesTempData => {
         if(lastDateLoaded === activitiesTempData.date){

             arr1[lastDateIndex].data = [...arr1[lastDateIndex].data, ...activitiesTempData.data];

         }else{
           arr1 = [...arr1, arr2];
         }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
arr1 =  [ 
  {date: "June 27", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
  {date: "June 24", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
  {date: "June 18", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
  {date: "June 14", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]}
]

arr2 = [ 
  {date: "June 14", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
  {date: "June 12", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
  {date: "June 10", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
  {date: "June 09", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]}
]

const result = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((a, c) => {
  let found = a.find(({ date }) => date === c.date);
  if (found) {
    found.data = [...found.data, ...c.data];
  } else {
    a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it didnt worked. I am getting only two values in data for "June 14" date.

Comment: @ArvindlalJaiswal, that's strange, the code snippet seems to run the expected result. Also tried it on my own console.

Comment: @ArvindlalJaiswal The important part is to merge the two arrays `[...arr1, ...arr2]` and reduce the resulting array.

Comment: Sorry @Titus and Christopher Ngo, it worked on console, but for my code it isn't working. will check my code once again and will get back. But thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Concat the arrays (or use array spread), and reduce them to a an object using the `date` as the key. Collect the `data` into the array at the relevant `date` key. Convert back to an object with `Object.values()`:

```js
const arr1 =  [{"date":"June 27","data":["dummyone","dummy2"]},{"date":"June 24","data":["dummyone","dummy2"]},{"date":"June 18","data":["dummyone","dummy2"]},{"date":"June 14","data":["dummyone","dummy2"]}]
const arr2 = [{"date":"June 14","data":["dummy3","dummy4"]},{"date":"June 12","data":["dummy3","dummy4"]},{"date":"June 10","data":["dummy3","dummy4"]},{"date":"June 09","data":["dummy3","dummy4"]}]

const result = Object.values([...arr1, ...arr2]
  .reduce((r, o) => {
    r[o.date] = r[o.date] ?
      { ...r[o.date], data: [...r[o.date].data, ...o.data] }
      :
      o
    
    return r
  }, {}))
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `forEach` ,`filter` and `concat` together to filter out the duplicate values

```js
var arr1 =  [ 
{date: "June 27", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
{date: "June 24", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
{date: "June 18", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
{date: "June 14", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]}
]

var arr2 = [ 
{date: "June 14", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
{date: "June 12", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
{date: "June 10", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
{date: "June 09", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]}
]
arr2.forEach(function(e) {
var arr=arr1.filter(function(r,j) {
      return r.date == e.date;
    })
  arr.length == 0?arr1.push(e): arr1[arr1.indexOf(arr[0])].data=arr1[arr1.indexOf(arr[0])].data.concat(e.data)  
})
console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to merge the `data` arrays of duplicates not just remove them. Also, in this cases (checkin if the array contains some kind of element), it is better to use `.some` instead of `.filter`.

Comment: Fiexd it @Titus

Answer (score 1):

We can merge two array using concat() method like this

```
  let arr1 =  [ 
{date: "June 27", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
{date: "June 24", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
{date: "June 18", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]},
{date: "June 14", data: ["dummyone","dummy2"]}
]

let arr2 = [ 
{date: "June 14", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
{date: "June 12", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
{date: "June 10", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]},
{date: "June 09", data: ["dummy3","dummy4"]}
]

console.log(arr1.concat(arr2));
```

This will print a merged array of these two array. Now after that if you want to remove duplicates record than you should use `lodash` library or other method of javascript like `filter(), reduce()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for combining arr1 and arr2? If so, try this

```
    var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2)
    console.log(arr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could graoup with a `Map` and get the grouped data in the wanted format.

```js
var arr1 = [{ date: "June 27", data: ["dummyone", "dummy2"] }, { date: "June 24", data: ["dummyone", "dummy2"] }, { date: "June 18", data: ["dummyone", "dummy2"] }, { date: "June 14", data: ["dummyone", "dummy2"] }],
    arr2 = [{ date: "June 14", data: ["dummy3", "dummy4"] }, { date: "June 12", data: ["dummy3", "dummy4"] }, { date: "June 10", data: ["dummy3", "dummy4"] }, { date: "June 09", data: ["dummy3", "dummy4"] }],
    result = Array.from(
        [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce(
            (m, { date, data }) => m.set(date, [...(m.get(date) || []), ...data]),
            new Map
        ),
        ([date, data]) => ({ date, data })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```